# In R I have a list that represents row index values, how do I return rows between two of these list elements?

Tags: r

EDIT:

I have this table (called document), and say I want to find information on Demand. All the rows from where Demand is to the next heading 1 are important so I want to extract just them (so I want rows 11 up to 19 (exclusive).

| doc_index | style_name | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | heading 1 | Demand |
| 12 | list bullet | blah blah blah |
| 13 | list bullet | blah blah blah 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 19 | heading 1 | Capital expenditure |
| 20 | list bullet | blah blah blah more |
| 21 | list bullet | blah blah blah etc |
| ... | ... | ... |

So: heading 1 -> in between text in form of list bullet -> heading 1
I want that middle bit.

I thought I would approach this by creating a list of all the doc_index corresponding to a heading 1 row.

```
headings <-document[document$style_name =="heading 1", ] 
heading_indexes <- c(headings$doc_index)
[1]  3  9 11 19 26 35 40 42 46 49 NA NA
```

From there I figured I'd find the heading index corresponding to the particular topic, ie. "demand".

```
topic <-document[document$text == "Demand", ] 
topic$doc_index
[1] 11
```

How do I get all the rows following that, so rows with doc_index 12,13,14,etc up until the next "heading 1" which has the doc_index of 19, which is stored in the headings_indexes list.

---

Original:
I have a list = [ 3  9 11 19 26 35 40 42 46 49 ] that corresponds to the index for important rows in a table.

What I want to achieve is to start at a particular index, say 11 and return all the rows from there up until the next important row which is at index 19, so the next element in the list.

How would I go about doing this? Conceptually I'm thinking a for loop but I've played around with no luck.

Could someone please suggest an approach I could take to this?

Comment: That's not R code for a list. We cannot infer whether you have a real R list or (more likely) an R numeric atomic vector. Indexing rules are different for those two classes. Please improve your question so we can have a [MCVE] to work with and not spend extra effort with follow up questions when our code doesn't work with your imprecise description of R objects. You should show what efforts at "playing around" you have done, so people can get a better idea of the level of your current knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` to create a grouping index

```
document$grp <- cumsum(grepl("^heading \\d+$", document$style_name))
```

Then,  use this to `subset` the data based on the group

```
subset(document, grp == 1)
subset(document, grp == 2)
....
```

or `split` the data into a `list` and extract from the `list` using `[[` or `$`

```
lst1 <- split(document, document$grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
headings <-document[document$style_name  %in% "heading 1", ] 
heading_indexes <- headings$doc_index
topic <-document[document$text == "Demand", ] 

result <- document[(topic$doc_index + 1):heading_indexes[match(topic$doc_index, heading_indexes) + 1], ]
```